# How to use generic data type as parameter in data binding?

Tags: javascript, android, kotlin

```
object BindingAdapter {
   @BindingAdapter("app:displayDate")
        @JvmStatic
        fun startDate(appCompatTextView: AppCompatTextView, item: SpecialOfferItem) {
            try {
                var strDate = ""
                strDate =
                    DateUtils.utcToCurrentTimeZone(item.startDate)
                appCompatTextView.text = strDate
            } catch (e: ParseException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                appCompatTextView.text = ""
            }
        }

}
```

How to use SpecialOfferItem as a generic parameter. i want to make this function for multiple model class

Comment: It doesn't make sens since you wana use `item.startDate` ... just use whatever `item.startDate` type is ... or normal interface/base class

Comment: @Selvin I edited my code and this method body part will change as per my requirement I will use multiple fields so I have to pass class object

Answer (score -1):

```
class SomethingClass<T : BaseModel>{ 
@BindingAdapter("app:startDate")
    @JvmStatic
    fun startDate(appCompatTextView: AppCompatTextView, item: T) {
        try {
            var strDate = ""
            strDate =
                DateUtils.utcToCurrentTimeZone(item.startDate)
            appCompatTextView.text = strDate
        } catch (e: ParseException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            appCompatTextView.text = ""
        }
    }
}
```

let all your models and classes you want to pass in the method to inherit from the BaseModel which contains the attributes you want to use.

Comment: then why generic at all? you may use `BaseModel` directly

Comment: to make it possible to use the class with different cases

Comment: yyyy what? `item: BaseModel` will work whithout generics ... and with `startDate: SomeDateType` (instead item) you may bind any date

Comment: there is a general solve and specific solve
what I am trying to suggest is the general solve
both suggestions will solve the problem.
anyway dude, it is not the end of the world.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244971/discussion-between-anas-altarazi-and-selvin).